# How to download Podspec dependencies for local development

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

This seems like something that should be done very easily. I don't know why I just can't seem to find a simple answer to that.

I am creating a pod library that has a pod dependency.

So in my `.podspec`, I have a `s.dependency 'SomePod', '~> 1.0'`. Since I am writing my library using `SomePod`, I want the source files from it in order to import it and use it. Sure one way to do it is to have a PodFile in the repo and then pod install the `SomePod`.

But is there some other way to download the `somePod` dependency so that I can use it in my library? What is the best practice around that to have a clean structure?

FYI, I am using the [Cookie Cutter](https://github.com/cookiecutter-swift/FrameworkTemplate) library in order to generate all my project structure. What's left for me to do is download those podspec dependencies and avoid using Podfile and pod install since I already have a .xcworkspace generated from Cookie Cutter, so pod install won't like that and will go crazy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you could handle the dependency management with other Tools (Carthage etc.) or simply on your own (git clone + project integration), but as you are already providing a podspec for your lib, why not just stick to cocoapods for third party lib integration?

This would be the typical approach for your setup, as you just need to write a simple Podfile, assure that SomePod is fetched with the same version as defined in podspec and call pod install.

Advantages:

- you can still watch third party sources
- you can debug into third party lib
- you can compile, test & debug against the exact same version of SomePod that will be fetched from a client project of your lib (no need to keep versions manually in sync)